# URL format validation in code behind of textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m using one text box, the text box is user choice..

User can paste Text or Url's.. 
but User want to display a video link... must follow the given validation......

1. The text box text must have only one video link...
2. The video link format
   "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx-xx&feature=g-logo&context=G2093438FOAAAAAAABAA"
   (or)
   "http://youtu.be/xxxxxxx-xx"

[Note: xxxxxxx-xx -video filename]
3. The above format video only allowed. because user some time

how can i do for this validation? (during validation split functions.....)

Comment: Do you wont to check is URL well formed or is it valid link to video clip ?

Answer (score 0):

is there anything common in your URL?
if so then you can check that string  is present in URL or Not

<<********** Add following code in custom validators ServerValidate Event *>>

```
    string str = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    if(str.contains(your_matching_string))
    {
        args.IsValid = true;   
    }
    else
    {
       args.IsValid = false;   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RegularExpressionValidator` on the TextBox would do the trick, but you'll need to do some trial and error to come up with the right regex.

Here's a start: "^http://youtu.be/[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}"

For figuring out the rest, I can at least recommend [RadSoftware's Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/).

Comment: The text box not only allowed a Video URL... It is also allowed texts.... So User Input text means no validation is required, in the meantime If Input is URl, should validate the URL.....